# $expand of back links is not supported for mega tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

when I make a query for users with `$expand`:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/users?$expand=memberOf&api-version=1.6
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "$expand of back links is not supported for mega tenants."
        },
        "requestId": "2cafcaca-a59e-45ed-9217-9bb44a143f5b",
        "date": "2019-05-01T08:59:55"
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what this `mega tenant` is?

Answer (score 1):

A Mega-Tenant will typically refer to B2C/MSA tenants in the scope of Azure. Unfortunately back-linking is currently not supported in said mega-tenants.

If you are interested in this feature please post this in the Azure Feedback located here : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

And the product team will look into it if there is a high interest.